# jenkins delete workspace after a job in done on another Server

Tags: jenkins

I have two servers X.X.X.X and Y.Y.Y.Y . I have a jenkins job that first execute a job on X.X.X.X and then execute another Job on Y.Y.Y.Y-

to be more precise, I build on the Server X.X.X.X and then the job starts on Y.Y.Y.Y and on Y.Y.Y.Y, it used the mapped results of the build on X.X.X.X

I want to delete workspace on X.X.X.X, after a special command is done on Y.Y.Y.Y.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great way to do this.
You could make a job on x.x.x.x that deletes the workspace and is triggered by  the [parameterized remote trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/) plugin on y.y.y.y.

Having said that, I think you should strongly look at *why* you are doing this and eliminate the need rather than solving it.
You're going to run into problems when jobs are already running, and workspace either cannot be deleted (causing errors), or the workspace is deleted whilst a job is running causing errors.